# Upgrading spring from 3.0.5 to Spring 4.3, DelegatingFilterProxy initbean method throwing java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: spring

I have an application running on Java6, Spring 3.0.5, Hibernate 3, CXF 2.5 and glassfish3. Now I am upgrading to java8, Spring 4.3, Hibernate 4.3, CXF 3.0 and glassfish5.
After the upgrading, the application seems to be working fine at least with basic functionalities. But the problem I am facing is the filters are not getting initialized properly while deploying the application. `DelegatingFilterProxy` is not able to initialize the filter beans that we declared in the `web.xml` and the `application-context.xml`. Hence the filter is not being applied to the requests.

web.xml

```
  <listener>
         <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <filter>
         <filter-name>formatRequest</filter-name>
         <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
         <filter-name>formatRequest</filter-name>
         <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
   </filter-mapping>
```

application-context.xml

```
<bean id="formatRequest"
      class="org.api.filters.FormatRequestFilter" scope="request"/>
```

Exception coming in the server log

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.FacesRequestAttributes.setAttribute  (FacesRequestAttributes.java:125)
at org.springframework.web.context.request.AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:45)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:340)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1084)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:326)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.initFilterBean(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:235)
at org.springframework.web.filter.GenericFilterBean.init(GenericFilterBean.java:236)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:267)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:123)
```

**My findings till now**

RequestAttributes are coming empty in RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes() method. 
Following is the piece of code from RequestContextHolder.java where I observed the issue:

RequestContextHolder.java:

```
public static RequestAttributes getRequestAttributes() {
        RequestAttributes attributes = (RequestAttributes)requestAttributesHolder.get();
        if(attributes == null) {
                attributes = (RequestAttributes)inheritableRequestAttributesHolder.get();
        }

    return attributes;
}
```

RequestContextListener that we declared in the web.xml should set these attributes to RequestContextHolder. Somehow this is not happening and the RequestAttributes list is coming empty with the new deployment.

With spring3, `RequestContextListener` is called first and Request Attributes are set. Then the filter bean initialization is happening correctly. With spring4 `RequestContextListener` is getting invoked after the filter bean initialization hence the Request Attributes are empty while initializing the filters.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Comment: The request attributes should have been empty in the init phase. The `RequestContextListener` is only invoked for incoming requests NOT when constructing the application context. So I'm actually surprised that it worked in Spring 3. Also why is the filter request scoped, that doesn't seem the right thing to do.

Comment: I have some request specific things to be done in the filter bean.

Comment: I debugged the code while deploying, first the filter bean initialization is happening and then the RequestContextListener is called.
At AbstractRequestAttributesScope.get(AbstractRequestAttributesScope.java:45) the 'attibutes' is coming as FacesRequestAttributes instead of ServletRequestAttributes. This is where the issue is, we are not using JSF.

Comment: No the issue is that at deployment the init shouldn't happen and again a request scoped filter is a code smell in my book why do you need a new instance per request?

Comment: Thank you Dienum, your suggestion was helpful to solve our issue.

Comment: @MadhaviReddy What was the solution to this ? even, I am having a similar issue